# What does blue color mean?

Tags: meaning

I am confuse when people say blue. Because in Thai language dark blue and light blue are different and we have different words between blue. In English do you think they are different or same color between dark blue and light blue?

Comment: All colors can be light or dark, except black and white....

Comment: Google **colour gradient** and **primary colours** to get a better idea of how colours are described.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Lambie "except black" [are you sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack)?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I painted the ceiling light black? I painted the ceiling dark white? Come on, now. Black is only qualified by painters of paintings, when they choose to get into it.

Comment: I have had paint-choosing arguments with my partner about whether a very dark 'charcoal' could be called a kind of pale black.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  They are both types of blue in English.

Compare this with "red" and "pink".  These are called different colours in English.

Different languages divide up the space of colours differently. In some languages "pink" is just "light red".  In some languages (like Thai, Japanese etc) "light blue" has a different word from "dark blue".

Here is one picture [image] From the [xkcd color survey](https://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/)

And here is a map of part of the colour cube, from the same [survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D03qO.png)

[image]

Comment: +1 for referencing an actual study of actual colors as people use them!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great video explanation of how color terms vary across languages: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMqZR3pqMjg